# sp_executesql to update a temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sp-executesql

I commonly use, and can easily find documentation on the internet for **inserting** into a temp table from an `sp_executesql` command:

```
 insert into #temp (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
 )
 exec sp_executesql @myQueryString
```

However, what I am having trouble finding any documentation on, is how to **update** the temp table from `sp_executesql`, such as setting the already existing `column2` to a new value from the results of the stored procedure.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to use the `sp_executesql` resultset directly in an `UPDATE` statement.

You would need to insert the result into a different table variable / temp table / permanent table that you then use to do your update against `#temp`.

You can access the temp table directly from the code in `@myQueryString` though.

So for example if `@myQueryString` was `UPDATE #temp SET column1 = 2` this would also work.

Comment: Okay, tracking. That's unfortunate, but i'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possible but probably not worth it.  You can use openrowset to do this.  You can look at my example below:  You will need to replace the server name with the server in question.

```
use master 

go

drop table #tempT
create table #tempT
(
    name sysname

) 

insert into #tempT
values ('backupmediafamily')

select * from #tempT
update t 
set name = 'new'
from ( SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('sqloledb', 'server=YourServerName;database=master;trusted_connection=yes','exec msdb.dbo.sp_executesql N''select * from sys.tables''')) a
inner join #tempt t on t.name = a.name

select * from #tempT
```

If you wanted something a little more dynamic you could try this:

```
drop table #tempT
create table #tempT
(
    name sysname

) 

insert into #tempT
values ('backupmediafamily')

select * from #tempT
declare @sp_executesqltext nvarchar(max) = 'select * from sys.tables where name like ''%backup%'' '
select @sp_executesqltext = replace(@sp_executesqltext,'''','''''''''')
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'update t 
            set name = ''new''
            from ( ' +
    'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''sqloledb'', ''server='+@@SERVERNAME+';database=master;trusted_connection=yes'','  +
    '''exec msdb.dbo.sp_executesql N'''''+@sp_executesqltext+''''''')) a
    inner join #tempt t on t.name = a.name' 

exec sp_executesql @sql

select * from #tempT
```

Lots of quotes so it will be a treat to debug if things break.